# Jest spyOn() calls the actual function instead of the mocked

Tags: javascript, mocking, jestjs, redux-middleware

I'm testing `apiMiddleware` that calls its helper function `callApi`. To prevent the call to actual `callApi` which will issue the API call, I mocked the function. However, it still gets called.

**apiMiddleware.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const CALL_API = 'Call API';

export const callApi = (...arg) => {
  return axios(...arg)
    .then( /*handle success*/ )
    .catch( /*handle error*/ );
};

export default store => next => action => {
  // determine whether to execute this middleware
  const callAPI = action[CALL_API];
  if (typeof callAPI === 'undefined') {
    return next(action)
  }

  return callAPI(...callAPI)
    .then( /*handle success*/ )
    .catch( /*handle error*/ );
}
```

**apiMiddleware.spec.js**

```
import * as apiMiddleware from './apiMiddleware';

const { CALL_API, default: middleware, callApi } = apiMiddleware;

describe('Api Middleware', () => {

  const store = {getState: jest.fn()};
  const next = jest.fn();
  let action;

  beforeEach(() => {
    // clear the result of the previous calls
    next.mockClear();
    // action that trigger apiMiddleware
    action = {
      [CALL_API]: {
        // list of properties that change from test to test 
      }
    };
  });

  it('calls mocked version of `callApi', () => {
    const callApi = jest.spyOn(apiMiddleware, 'callApi').mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve());

    // error point: middleware() calls the actual `callApi()` 
    middleware(store)(next)(action);

    // assertion
  });
});
```

Please ignore the action's properties and argument of `callApi` function. I don't think they are the concern of the point I'm trying to make.

Tell me if you need further elaboration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The jest mocking only works on imported functions. In your `apiMiddleware.js` the `default` function is calling `callApi` variable, not the "exported" `callApi` function. To make the mock work, move `callApi` into its own module, and `import` it in `apiMiddleware.js`

Good question!

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issues converting my code to a `Class`, example:

```js
// Implementation 
export class Location {
  getLocation() {
    const environment = this.getEnvironmentVariable();
    return environment === "1" ? "USA" : "GLOBAL";
  }
  getEnvironmentVariable() {
    return process.env.REACT_APP_LOCATION;
  }
}


// Test
import { Location } from "./config";

test('location', () => {
  const config = new Location();
  jest.spyOn(config, "getEnvironmentVariable").mockReturnValue("1")

  const location = config.getLocation();
  expect(location).toBe("USA");
});
```